# DDMS Files Not Found Android\platform-tools\adb.exe

Tags: java, android

I have Eclipse and Java SE and am running Windows XP and am trying to setup Android for Eclipse.

I first:

Visit http://developer.android.com. 
2. On the main page that appears, click the link to download the Android SDK. 
3. Find a link appropriate to your operating system (Windows, Mac OS X, or Linux). 
4. Click the link to begin the download.

I installed the Android SDK Tools

I then installed ADT as followed ( note I used http instead of https ) under downloading the ADT plugin.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

It gave me some errors saying that somethings needed to be installed which would have been installed if i'd installed Java EE.

I saw a site that said go into the SDK Manager, so I tried installing somethind and it gave me this error:

[2012-06-28 14:32:27 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: K:\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe 
[2012-06-28 14:32:27 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: K:\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe

What does this mean, and how can I get Android to work. Do I still need some thigns that Java EE has for Android?

Comment: Try open eclipse as Administrator, indeed download Java EE, if indigo does problems try helios

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hate to say it, but restart Eclipse.  My recent install gets confused sometimes and that's how I fix it.  Hasn't failed to correct it yet.

Comment: I have a similar problem with [2014-07-10 21:18:49 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\hprof-conv.exe 
[2014-07-10 21:18:50 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\hprof-conv.exe 
 Except in my case the files are actually there.

Answer (score 2):

The file path is wrong. You probably renamed a file in the directory after you installed Eclipse, and now you have to change the file path manually or re-install the program. That's why in the instructions, you are asked to install to developer on your main drive, and not some other file.

Answer (score 0):

After moving eclipse to another drive I experienced this problem.  Fix it by setting the SDK folder at Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Android > SDK Location:

Changing the Drive letter from C to E fixed this for me.  Locate your eclipse folder on your drive and correct the path or use the browse button.

The path for me was E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

Shutdown any other app that might be connecting to the phone via adb.exe eg. Visual Studio using android sdk.

Restart eclipse if needed.

Answer (score 0):

install the installer from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools andriod intaller it will be all right

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Set your SDK path in Preferences (Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Android > SDK Location:)