# DDMS files not found Error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I had the some **`DDMS files not found...`** problem.

I fixed it by making sure that the Android SDK path is set correctly in Eclipse (which is **C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk** on my machine).

This can be done in **Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Android->SDK Location.**

plz help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you updated your android sdk or ADT??

Comment: yes,I have updated it..but still i m having a problem...@RDC

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253669/ddms-files-not-found-android-platform-tools-adb-exe ?

Comment: Another suggestion for you is that change the Place of your SDK because if your window is currupted in any case then you will be in trouble. So place this SDK in anyother drive.

Comment: I had a same problem and fixed it. <br>
Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094017/ddms-files-not-found-sdk-home-tools-traceview-eclipse/43147964#43147964

Answer (score 1):

Root cause:

1. Android may not be installed only fetching might have done in eclipse.
2. Check the location of android installation in eclipse windows -> preferences -> android (installation path may not be correct).

Solution:

1. Give the correct android installed path in windows -> preferences -> android.
2. If you not able to find the path, better uninstall and install the android again.

Android download link for windows:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You first restart your eclipse and check it.

- If again throws same error please try this steps
- I had same problem and fixed it using the following
  link

[DDMS files not found: SDK_HOME/tools/traceview : Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094017/ddms-files-not-found-sdk-home-tools-traceview-eclipse/43147964#43147964)

Answer (score 0):

I think, your folder *'tools'* in *android-sdk* folder is incomplete. Maybe, during updating your download broken or not enough space and the update stopped.
Whatever.
You can download only the tools from android sdk. You find it here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools

And copy the content of *tools* inside your *android-sdk* folder, that the folder *tools* is complete with all necessary files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of android studio DDMS is deprecated but you can choice another option

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Quote:

> Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. The features that you could use through the Android Device Monitor have been replaced by new features. The table below helps you decide which features you should use instead of these deprecated and removed features.