# DDMS files not found: SDK_HOME/tools/traceview : Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-neon

I'm newly configured Android Eclipse neon in Ubuntu. When I try to open the eclipse it throws error As 
 "**Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK. The Android Development Toolkit may not work properly**"

I have tried many references but i am unable to solve the issue as given in references to reinstall ADT plugin.Which i have tried many times and does not solve the issue.

[The Message shown in dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsCTo.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got an answer.

You **first restart your eclipse** and check it. 
If again throws same error please try this steps:
 1. Download latest **SDK tools package** package from google.[Download here end of the page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#download).
2. Extract the tools package.
3. Replace **Exract folder(ToolsPackage)** to ANDROID_SDK_DIRECTORY/**tools** folder.
4. Now fixed the issue. works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was download the SDK TOOLS folder from the url:

https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKTools (Android SDK Tools 26.0.2)

then find the path where the SDK is installed
MAC OS: open //Library/Android/sdk/

and overwrite folder tools

[image]