# DDMS file not found error. Android. Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, ddms

I downloaded Eclipse, adt plugin, sdk files and the Java and been developing apps since about a month. But suddenly the debugger started showing errors. DDMS file not found. The path for sdk too is correct. What should I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DDMS files not found Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127476/ddms-files-not-found-error)

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse. Another answer from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253669/ddms-files-not-found-android-platform-tools-adb-exe)